# ¿Por qué el comando "at" no ejecuta un comando que le programo?

Tags: linux

Tengo un problema con el comando `at` de Linux. Está arrancado el daemon y el comando parece funcionar correctamente pero no llega a ejecutar nada.

Tengo un archivo .sh llamado prueba.sh con el siguiente texto:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Hola Mundo bash
```

En Linux pongo los comandos:

```
chmod 700 prueba.sh
at now + 2 minutes
at> sh prueba.sh
```

El resultado es este:

at> job 19 at Thu Jan 31 08:49:00 2019

Pero no ejecuta el mensaje a los dos minutos.

Comment: ¿ No **ejecuta** o **no muestra nada por pantalla** ? Son cosas **muy** distintas. Cambiar tu `prueba.sh` y pon `touch /home/MISUSUARIO/prueba.dat`, a ver si te crea o no el archivo.

Answer (score 2):

El comando at no usa la salida estándar, si lees su [*man*](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at) encontrarás:

> The user will be mailed standard error and standard output from his
>   commands, if any. Mail will be sent using the command
>   /usr/sbin/sendmail.

Traducción:

> Se le mandará al usuario un email con la salida estándar y la salida
>   de errores de sus comandos. El email será enviado con el comando
>   /usr/sbin/sendmail

Answer (score -1):

Para que te funcione el comando deberias ver esta URL: https://blog.desdelinux.net/ejecuta-un-comando-a-la-hora-que-quieras-con-at/. Tienes que ejecutarlo como administrador. Un saludo.

Comment: Las respuestas con un enlace unicamente se consideran de mala calidad debido a que la página enlazada puede desaparecer.